# Finding the loading time of Swf in browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4

Finding the loading time of Swf in browser
Hi,
   i need to find the loading time of swf in Milli-seconds,the project is done in flash cs4 prof and its run in browser with flash player 10 ... 
Is there any tool to find the exact loading time taken by the application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try Yslow addon for Firefox.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/help/index.html

Answer (score 0):

in the safari develop menu (on a mac), you can open the web inspector resources tab to look at the ms loading time of every resource on a page, including swfs. Just out of curiosity, what is the end goal of getting the loading time? you can use the test features in cs4 to simulate a download to check download times on different bandwidths, and save yourself the trouble of uploading the file to the server first.

Answer (score 0):

could make another swf to load that swf, and find the elapsed time during loading.